# How do I pick only one record per ID based on the earliest date in another column?

Tags: text-processing, command-line

I have a file containing multiple lines, with fields separated by *tab*:

```
ID Code Date
1  XX   23/1/2018
1  XX   11/3/2021
2  XX   14/5/2011
2  XX   20/9/2013
3  XX   08/7/2014
3  XX   11/9/2016
3  XX   27/10/2018
```

I would like to keep for each participant `ID` just one entry, based on the entry with the earliest date in the `Date` column. For each participant, the dates are ordered from oldest to newest.

The output I would like is:

```
1  XX   23/1/2018
2  XX   14/5/2011
3  XX   08/7/2014
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you state that the records for each participant are ordered from oldest to newest, and you want to print only the record with the oldest date for each `ID`, this amounts to printing the first row encountered for each new `ID`. This is easily possible using `awk`:

```bash
awk -F'\t' 'FNR>1 && !seen[$1]++' input.txt
```

This will first set the field separator to `\t`. Then, it will evaluate the condition between `' ... '` to decide whether to print the current line. A line will be printed if

- the per-file line-counter is larger than one (in order to skip the header line), *and*
- the array `seen` does not yet contain an entry for the current value of the first column (`$1`). This works because dereferencing an array value that was not yet assigned evaluates to `false`. Also, the postfix operator `++` will only be applied after this evaluation, so for the first encounter of a specific `ID` this returns true, but for any later encounters, where `seen[$1]` is larger than 0, it will return `false` and thereby inhibit printing of the line.

If you want to keep the header line, just remove the `FNR>1` condition:

```bash
awk -F'\t' '!seen[$1]++' input.txt
```

(It will be printed, because the `ID` of this line is *literally* `ID`, and of course the first occurence of that particular value.)

Comment: thank you, this is very helpful.

Answer (score 2):

The following uses [Miller](https://miller.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) (`mlr`, a tool for processing structured data) to parse the records in the TSV file.  It groups the records by the `ID` value and outputs *the first* found value in each group:

```bash
$ mlr --tsv head -g ID -n 1 file
ID      Code    Date
1       XX      23/1/2018
2       XX      14/5/2011
3       XX      08/7/2014
```

If the dates are *not* sorted for each `ID`, we may sort them by converting each date string into a Unix timestamp and sorting numerically on this new field.  After sorting, we do the same `head` operation as above and then re-sort on the `ID` value after cutting out (removing) the timestamp field.

```bash
mlr --tsv \
    put '$ts = strptime($Date, "%d/%m/%Y")' then \
    sort -n ts then \
    head -g ID -n 1 then \
    cut -x -f ts then \
    sort -n ID file
```

The output is identical for the example shown in the question.

Comment: thank you, I will ask for "Miller" to be uploaded to the TRE. This looks great.

Answer (score 1):

You can obtain the desired output using this code:

```
sed 1d file_of_data | sort -k1,2n -u
```

What this does is,

1. use `sed` to discard (delete) the first line containing headers
2. `sort` the resulting file numerically by the first column, discarding duplicates (of that sort field)

Output

```
1  XX   23/1/2018
2  XX   14/5/2011
3  XX   08/7/2014
```

Comment: thank you - really helpful.

Comment: have noted the tick, thank you. I was just reviewing the output and I only get 1813 records when there are 8358 uniq records. It also looks like it has picked up at times not the first date entry. Any possibility to fix this?

Comment: @Julia This would be easier to debug if you can look at the output and find instances of the code doing the wrong thing, and then updating your question with additional test data that triggers the problematic behaviour. The code in this answer evidently works and does the correct processing of the given example data.

Comment: @Julia By "uniq record", what do you mean? How many unique IDs are there? Note that the whole issue is to reduce the number of records by grouping them by the `ID` field.

Comment: Hello Kusalananda, when I was referring to uniq records I meant uniq IDs. There are 8358 uniq IDs. Each ID has multiple dates for the same diagnosis, and I am interested the first time they were dagnosed.